# Toggling draft mode using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, layouts

I'm curious if it is possible to toggle on and off 'draft mode' in layout view in ArcGIS using python scripting.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Python is preferred, but if there is another solution in a different language it would also be beneficial!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with this feature but there seems to be some .net methods and properties:

[IFrameElement.DraftMode Property](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//001200000520000000)

AND

[IFrameDraw.DrawDraftMode Method](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/DrawDraftMode_Method/00120000051s000000/)

Answer (score 0):

If it were possible to do this then there should be a property to do it in the [DataFrame (arcpy.mapping) help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s300000003000000).

There is not, and to me that makes sense because draft mode seems to be a graphic effect of the ArcMap application.

To do something which is effectively the same, I think you will need to write some ArcPy code to save your layers (perhaps as layer files) and remove them when you want to toggle them off, and to restore your layers by adding them back when you toggle them on.